# Manuell Postback in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, postback

how I can do a manuell postback in the code?

I don't want a Redirect, because e.g. the user has entered values in fields in the site and decide than to login. I only want a simple Postback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have link/image buttons on you page you can do:

```
__doPostBack('link/image button name',''); // in javascript
```

or if not:

```
var f = document.forms[0]; //if you only have one forms(this standard on asp.net)
f.__EVENTTARGET = 'some control name';
f.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your point? Do you want to generate a postback script?

```
Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "Arguments", false);
```

Afterward, for handling the postback you must implement the `System.Web.UI.IPostbackEventHandler`.

But if you want a cross postback, check it out:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/xpgpostbk_asp2_dc08102006235543PM/xpgpostbk_asp2_dc.aspx